# Reference an environmental variable into a cloud flow

Tags: power-automate

I have a power flow that is triggered by a HTTP request. I have added a trigger condition by requiring a key to restrict unauthorized calls, like seen below:
[image]

I want to store this key to an environmental variable and reference this value to trigger condition.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the environment variable value in Power automate cloud flow trigger conditions using syntax like:

```
parameters('MyEnvVariable (cr86e_MyEnvVariable)')
```

Where `MyEnvVariable` is Display name and `cr86e_MyEnvVariable` is Name of environment variable.

[image]

---

Assuming your environment variable display name and name is as given in above example, you can use trigger condition like:

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()['headers']?['runKey'],parameters('MyEnvVariable (cr86e_MyEnvVariable)'))
```